# AngularJS allows POST or PUT to web service crossing domain?

Tags: javascript, web-services, angularjs, cors

Now, I am able to GET data from API on a web service in AngularJS using `$http` or `$resource` but I cannot POST or PUT date to update API on the same web service.
The error I got is the cross-origin issue which is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://rm.ws.localhost.dev/bookings/36.json. Origin http://rm.localhost.dev is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

In Angular, the code as follow enables to "GET" data,

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

In addition, I changed configure file on web service server, added two lines:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

All these make me access web service by GET data, cannot PUT or POST. Where I went wrong or I miss something. I thought Angular supports POST and PUT. Thanks all.

Comment: you can see some more info @:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34613675/4274373 hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the API/web service server is not handling an OPTIONS request.  A cross-origin PUT will always result in the browser "preflighting" the request (via an OPTIONS request) first.  A cross-origin POST with [non-simple headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-header) will also be preflighted in this manner.  The server must acknowledge the underlying method and the underlying non-simple headers (as well as the Origin) in the response to the OPTIONS request.  Please note that cross-origin PUT and non-simple POSTs will never work in IE9 or older, as cross-origin ajax requests must be made with XDomainRequest in those browsers, which does not support preflighting.